# Calling a function from a dynamically loaded DLL

Tags: c++, windows

I need to implement some functionality of the otherwise monolithic application via DLL that is loaded at runtime. (Think about a customized DLL -- different for each customer.)

The Visual C++ from VS 2013 is used.

The application gets the full name name of the DLL. The function to be called has a fixed name (`convert` in my case) and fixed number and type of the arguments (a reference to a constant vector of strings -- see the `cref_vs` below). This means the function is implemented in C++.

I have modified the example from the MSDN doc, and it seems to work. However, I must be sure I did not overlooked something important. Here is the code (simplified) to load the DLL and call the function:

```
typedef const std::vector<std::string> & cref_vs;
typedef int(*CONVERTPROC)(cref_vs vs);
```

Notice that unlike in the official example that mixes calling a C code in DLL from a C++ function, I do not use `__cdecl`. I guess that this way I can reliably pass a C++ object (like a vector of strings). Is it correct?

```
int call_convert_from_dll(const std::string & dllname, 
                          const std::vector<std::string> & vs)
{
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;
    CONVERTPROC convert;
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE;

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(dllname.c_str());

    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.
    if (hinstLib != nullptr) {
        convert = (CONVERTPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "convert");

        // If the function address is valid, call the function.
        if (convert != nullptr) {
            (convert)(vs);
        }

        // Free the DLL module.
        fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
    }

    if (!fRunTimeLinkSuccess)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, because I want the unmangled name of the function inside the DLL, I need to use `extern "C"`, and it must be exported via `__declspec(dllexport)`. However, I do not want to use `__cdecl` calling convention:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport) int convert(const std::vector<std::string> & vs)    
{
    cout << "my.dll -- convert called with arguments:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
         cout << argv[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}


} // extern "C"
```

Can you confirm that I am doing it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, but I won't hold it against you. ;)

I'd suggest reading up on using C++ with DLLs in a compatible fashion, and would suggest this [excellent article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL#CppMatureApproach) as a good place to start. This article also touches on exporting STL types, which your code is doing.

So, the question is, how portable/robust do you need/expect your approach to be? If you need developers from anywhere to be able to plug into your system, stick to a C interface if possible (avoiding STL types -- pass a `char**` across the boundary, and convert that on the C++ side to an STL `vector<string>`). Otherwise, upgrade to a virtual class based system -- and make sure that you don't directly use STL, but instead use virtual class wrappers for those types as well. Note that this carries on -- e.g., if you want to use an iterator class used by the STL type you're wrapping, you'll need another abstract (iterator) class that your abstract (iterable) class references, so it can get a little ugly.

Minor code notes...

- `fFreeResult` is assigned, but never used.
- `fRunTimeLinkSuccess` is not set (after initialization).
- The "convert" string might better be contained in a macro (or a small set of macros), so that your plugin clients can declare a convert function, and you can refer to that function name without the possibility of typo.
- Your example plugin refers to `argc` and `argv` that don't exist.

Comment: @LokiAstari Good catch on fRunTimeLinkSuccess never changing from its initialized value.

Comment: For the `fRunTimeLinkSuccess` -- corrected. I did remove some other lines. This one should stay there. For the `argc` and `argv`. This was actually copied from another version of the code (my fault), that was passed the arguments from the command line (for testing). The newer version parses the string from a file (`StringTok` to `vector<string>`. So, I should do the opposite way -- to convert `vector<string>` to the `int` and `char*[]`, right? Thanks, I will be back after reading the article.

Comment: Thanks for the article. It seems that it will be better to pass the `char*` (the string from a file) and wrap the function body to the `try`/`catch` to avoid exceptions bubble from DLL to the caller (returning integer error code).

Comment: Please, have a look at the second version http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48260/16189